# Strategy for multiple projects of git under one project

Tags: git, version-control

This question will not be presenting codes. Because I want to know the proper way of using multiple projects inside one project versioned in git.

Let's say I have a master project. And I cloned other dependency projects under subdirectories. What is the standard way to do that?

For example:

Let's say I have cloned Wordpress.

Then I cloned latest OpenSource template under themes folder.
And I cloned latest OpenSource plugins under plugins folder.

Each of the sub projects will contain .git folder.

Would I just add them(`.git`) to `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [git submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) to manage your subprojects.

Under your master project, execute the following commands to add and clone two subprojects:

```
git submodule add https://example/project1.git themes/project1
git submodule add https://example/project2.git themes/project2
git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score 3):

If the "subprojects" are dependencies on which you don't usually develop inside of your superproject, and if the subprojects are git repos, a common way to do this is [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). Initializing or cloning a submodule, will tell the containing git repo to ignore the contents of that folder, and only remember which revision of the dependency repo you currently have checked out.
If the dependencies are not git repos, from a git point of view you would just add them to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Would that be a good idea if I contribute to the subprojects which is under my master project?

Comment: @Lenin: It's definitely possible; the submodules are just normal git repos of themselves (what's making them submodules is that the super-repo knows about them). Some people find it inconvenient, though. You can read a bit more about submodules under the link in Neevek's answer, and here on SO and Google you'll find a lot more discussion about the good's and bad's of submodules.

Comment: Thanks both of your answers are acceptable, so just chosen one.